I need to jiggle the cable to keep the vaccum on. Should I replace it?
I have a vacuum and in order for it to start/stay on I need to "jiggle" the cable around the plug. At times I use a tape so that it stays on. See image

Is this something fixable/safe? Should I replace the vacuum? Also did this happen because the plug I normally use is high up in the wall?
UPDATE
It is the vacuum that has the issue. Other appliances turn on immediately and the vacuum has a problem with other outlets

It is the vacuum that has the issue ... probably not ... your description indicates a bad power cord and/or a bad power plug at end of power cord

Jiggling the cable to get the power to stay on is definitely an unsafe condition. Loose connections like this start fires.
If other things plugged into that outlet stay on just fine, and only the vacuum has trouble, then the vacuum cord, or at least the plug, needs replacing.
If other items plugged into this outlet require jiggling to stay in, then the outlet's in-wall cables need tightening, or the outlet needs replacing.
If you don't have the DIY skills to handle these repairs safely, you should get a friend who does, or an electrician, as needed. You need an electrician especially if you live in a rental home and it's the outlet at fault.

Only the vacuum has the issue.

OK, then just replacing the plug is necessary. If you do replace the plug and the problem is still there, it could be a break down the wire within the loop that you've taped up. Cut off past the taped loop and put the plug on the new end.

I don't know how to do that. Would it be expensive so better to replace the vaccum? –

A new plug is a lot less expensive than a new vacuum. "If you don't have the DIY skills to handle these repairs safely, you should get a friend who does, or an electrician, as needed." (Try for the friend, the electrician may drive the cost up above a new vacuum.)

replacement plugs are cheap. And replacing it only needs a screwdriver and some skill with a pair of cutters

@ratchetfreak:Is there any good YT video or similar to understand what's required?

@Jim That would be a web-search. Find one that's understandable to you.

Do you think it happened because the plug is high up the wall? How can I make sure this won't happen again? Is there something use to protect the cable(s)? I assume this was caused by having the cable moving around during cleaning

@Jim   It is more wear and tear on the plug/wire where it goes into the plug.   I even had it happen to a welder's plug and they just sit there not being moved much.  It is a simple fix, two wires to attach to screws.  A simple inexpensive wire stripper and a screwdriver is all you really need.

In my opinion replacing an appliance plug is an ideal beginner electrical DIY task. but if you're not confident to do this yourself, it's a 5 minute task for an appliance technician, so assuming you can take it to their shop the labor charge will be small.

@Jasen: Do the wires need to be connected to the plug in a specific order or it does not matter?I mean when attaching them to the new plug

there is a specific pattern, if you buy the replacement plug retail it will come with pictorial instructions. if not you can search online.  most vacuum cleaners use only two wires in their cable the connect to the two pins of the plug.

@Jim how to replace a plug is a good new question to ask.

If it's the outlet that's the issue (check with others) then you can replace just the outlet. You should only need a screwdriver to do so. Remember to turn off the breaker when doing so.
You can replace just the plug. A DIY store will have replacement plugs available. Cut the cable back a but and strip back the insulation. Then connect the wires up.
It looks like a European style molded plug without ground so you can leave the ground connection of the plug unconnected.

It is the vacuum that has the issue actually

@Jim It is not the vacuum. The fault is either in the cord, and/or the plug, and/or the power socket.
